# Creating post form with form name as holder

Tags: html

How can I create form where form name is container for all form posts.

This is what I got:

```
Array ( [senderName] => gsdfg [receiverAddress] => asdf [receiverEmail] => asd@asd [xSize] => 2 [ySize] => 3 [zSize] => 4 [units] => cm [weight] => 22 )
```

but what I want is:

```
Array ( [form] => array([senderName] => gsdfg [receiverAddress] => asdf [receiverEmail] => asd@asd [xSize] => 2 [ySize] => 3 [zSize] => 4 [units] => cm [weight] => 22 ))
```

(giving form name attribute doesnt resolve my problem)

This is my html:

```
<form action="http://dev.playgroundwp.lv/?page_id=24" id="productForm" method="post">

                <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="sender-name-input">Your Name*:</label>
                                    </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="senderName" value="" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name" id="sender-name-input">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="receiver-address-input">Receiver Address*:</label>
                                    </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="receiverAddress" value="" required="required" placeholder="Enter place" id="receiver-address-input">

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="receiver-email-input">Receiver Email*:</label>
                                    </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="email" name="receiverEmail" value="" required="required" placeholder="Enter email" id="receiver-email-input">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="x-size-input">Size*:</label>
                                    </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- type number nestrādās škiet uz ie < 9, jāskatās cik tālu nepieciešams supports -->
                    <input type="number" placeholder="x" name="xSize" required="required" min="0" value="" step="0.01" id="x-size-input">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="y" name="ySize" required="required" min="0" value="" step="0.01" id="y-size-input">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="z" name="zSize" required="required" min="0" value="" step="0.01" id="z-size-input">
                    <select name="units" placeholder="select units" id="units-input">
                        <option value="mm">mm</option>
                        <option value="cm">cm</option>
                        <option value="m">m</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="weight-input">Weight*:</label>
                                    </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="kg" name="weight" min="0" value="" step="0.01" required="required" id="weight-input">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <button type="submit" value="submitted">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

How can I achieve that without using js?

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between the name of a form (which should be avoided in favour of an id anyway) and the data it sends to the server.

If you want PHP to create an associative array of values then you must give the form *controls* names that will trigger that:

```
name="form[senderName]"
```